# Writing into a file overwrites rather then adding to next line

Tags: c++

```cpp
class user {
    string name;
    int date;
 
    void user_info(void)
    {
        cout << "Enter your Name : " << endl;
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter your Age :" << endl;
        cin >> date;
        
    }
    
    void add_leaderboard(void) {
        fstream myFile;
        myFile.open("Leaderboard.txt", fstream::app);
        if (myFile.is_open()) {
            myFile << name << " " << date <<   "\n";

            myFile.close();
        }
    }
};

void get_info() {
    user person;
    person.user_info();
    person.add_leaderboard();
    return;
}
```

I have this code and I thought I opened it so that it would continue on the next line however no matter what I change fstream:: to it still overwrites my text file.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but that `if (myFile.is_open())` doesn’t really accomplish anything. If the stream isn’t open, the insertions have no effect. And if you remove `myFile.close()`the destructor will take care of things.

Comment: Hacked out a runnable bit of code based in your code, but unable to reproduce. This suggests that the changes I made to get your code compiling fixed the bug or you left something out. Please make a [mre] (a MRE) that  we can run to see the problem in action and replace the current code example with it, assuming making the MRE doesn't end prematurely with you finding and fixing the problem yourself.

Comment: The code doesn’t read from the file, so the file should be an output file:  `std::ofstream myFile(“Leaderboard.txt”, std::ios::app);`.

Comment: Oh son of a gun. It's just an `fstream`, not an `ofstream`. Didn't see that. Wonder why g++ lets that pass?

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/ro4PncKP3). Don't forget to tell your prof I get the A, ;) (The answer is detailed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream), which is now your homepage)

Comment: thank you it was literally just fstream was meant to be ofstream I hate how small things like that dont get detected.